# Folder jquery error

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I have a Java application with JSF.
I added the following tags in the page header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js"></script>
```

But when inspecting the page it presents the errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 
(Internal Server Error) jquery-1.10.2.min.js`> 
Failed to load resource:
the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 
jquery.fancybox.pack.js`> 
Failed to load resource: the server responded
with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.elevateZoom-
3.0.8.min.js
```

UPDATE

My view folders architecture

[image]

Browser Jquery
[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWPNI.jpg)

Comment: The files are in a folder called js, but the js folder is not in the WEB-INF folder, I updated the image with the architecture view of my folders

Comment: I put the js folder in WEB-INF and the error persisted